# EF SaveChanges Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tblStmtTask_StmtBatchID". The conflict occurred in database "CRM", table "dbo.tblStmtBatch", column 'ID'.

The statement has been terminated

I"m getting this error while saving a modification to 'tblStmtTask' .. I understand that I have a foreign key to the 'tblStmtBatch', but I haven't a clue why changing an unrelated column in the task should have any impact on the batch.

How do I decipher what the root cause of this error actually is ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that updates the entity. Check whether the foreign key property of the entity actually has a value.

Comment: yes, that IS the problem...it started out as a 14...but now its a 0....where'd it go?  quick investigation shows that it exists when I load the row on the first half of the edit in the controller.

Comment: Rather difficult for me to say, but if the entity is updated in a form, and your ActionMethod looks something like this `public ActionResult Edit(Entity entity)` then it won't automatically fill in the foreign key property. You could send it along using the `@Html.HiddenFor` HTML helper. Obviously this is only one (but I guess a common way to lose the FK value). Easiest way is to track down where it "get's lost" is so place a breakpoint at the creation of the entity and then check step-by-step.

Comment: yes, quite so.  Care to fill out an 'answer' so I can credit you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a breakpoint on the update statement. The FK property will be empty. In order to find the step where it is set to empty your best bet is to breakpoint the point of creation of the entity and step through it so can pinpoint the place where the FK gets set to empty.

If the FK property is empty at creation there has been a problem with mapping. If the entity is being created with the DefaultModelBinder, make sure you have provided the FK property in your form as well, e.g. using the `@Html.HiddenFor` HTML helper.